# How do I remove specific words from columns?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I need to remove "km" from `distance` column:

```
[Distance]
0     114 km
1     114 km
2     9.1 km
3    33.1 km
4     182 km
5    93.2 km
6    40.4 km
7        0.0
8        0.0
9    43.4 km
Name: distance, dtype: object
```

Has to look like this:

```
[Distance]
0     114
1     114
2     9.1
3    33.1
4     182
5    93.2
6    40.4
7        
8        
9    43.4
```

Comment: Is it expected to have empty strings in place of 0?

Comment: yeah or just dropping the columns, but they are not NaN's so I'm figuring out how to remove all 0 rows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the 4 options in my answer to see if any one suits you?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the trailing substring to remove is always `km`, you can use:

```
df['distance'] = df['distance'].str.replace(r'\s*km$', '', regex=True)
```

A more generic method would be to extract the number:

```
df['distance'] = df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

If you only want the number when there is "km":

```
df['distance'] = df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*km')
```

And to convert to numeric/NaN:

```
df['distance'] = pd.to_numeric(df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*km', expand=False), errors='coerce')
```

##### summary

```
df['distance1'] = df['distance'].str.replace(r'\s*km$', '', regex=True)

df['distance2'] = df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')

df['distance3'] = df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*km')

df['distance4'] = pd.to_numeric(df['distance'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*km', expand=False), errors='coerce')

print(df.dtypes)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
distance      object
distance1     object
distance2     object
distance3     object
distance4    float64
dtype: object

  distance distance1 distance2 distance3  distance4
0   114 km       114       114       114      114.0
1   114 km       114       114       114      114.0
2   9.1 km       9.1       9.1       9.1        9.1
3  33.1 km      33.1      33.1      33.1       33.1
4   182 km       182       182       182      182.0
5  93.2 km      93.2      93.2      93.2       93.2
6  40.4 km      40.4      40.4      40.4       40.4
7      0.0       0.0       0.0       NaN        NaN
8      0.0       0.0       0.0       NaN        NaN
9  43.4 km      43.4      43.4      43.4       43.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to simply drop the observations with 0 and remove the 'km':

```
df['distance'] = df['distance'].str.replace(r'[a-z]', '').astype('float')
# r'[a-z]' means any character between a-z
df['distance'] = df['distance'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['distance'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way I could provide as below,

```
distance = ['114 km', '114 km', '9.1 km',
            '33.1 km', '182 km', '93.2 km',
            '40.4 km', '0.0', '0.0', '43.4 km']

dist_df = pd.DataFrame(data=distance,
                       index=[k for k in range(len(distance))],
                       columns=["distance"])
print('''{}
Original DataFrame:
{}
'''.format("*"*20, dist_df))

# Straight-forward way
for i in range((len(dist_df))):
    dist_df.loc[i, "distance"] = dist_df.loc[i, "distance"].strip(" km")
print('''{}
Original DataFrame:
{}
'''.format("*"*20, dist_df))
```

The result is:
[image]

Or you could re-write the functions like this:

[image]